# Get cashed line number and function name in ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, symbolicatecrash

Im making a sample in which i have found the "**crash trace**" by using 
[unchaught execption handler](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html).

now problem is that i have to find the excat line number where the exception is raised .

Please help and thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the breakpoint button on the project navigator and then at the bottom of your project navigtor you can find a + sign, click on it and then select Add Exception Breakpoint. That will add you  an all exception breakpoint so you can find the exact line where the exception is raised.

[image]

Comment: Actually your answer is an debugging technique my question is that when an application is crashed it just go into a method i.e NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler); over which we can get we can get reason , traces of the exception but the problem is that we are not getting the excat line number where the crash occured .